# update all but latest duplicate rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table where there is a user identifier(not unique because the same user can have 2 entries) and a creation date. I want to mark all but the newest copy of each user in some manner

Example
User  Date

```
1    | oct 5
2    | oct 7
3    | oct 6
1    | oct 6
```

In this example the row corresponding to user 1 oct 5 should have some value updated. Is there an easy way I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some sort of flag to the table:

```
alter table example add column IsNewest int default 1;
```

Then you can update it as:

```
update example e left join
       (select user, max(date) as maxd
        from example
        group by user
       ) eu
       on e.user = eu.user and e.date = eu.maxd
    set IsNewest = 0
    where eu.date is null;
```

Of course, to keep this up-to-date, you'll need triggers for inserts, deletes, and updates.  It might be simpler to just do the calculation when you fetch the rows from the table.